# Ruby Trying to get a 3 line return

Tags: ruby, newline

Hi I'm trying to get the program to return all three lines on top of one another when a 5 is entered. It's only returning the third line. This is Ruby. (My first time trying it)

```
 moveOne = gets.to_i
 if moveOne == 5
 puts =  "1,2,X"
         "4,O,6"
         "X,8,9"
```

Comment: The accepted answer is good, but I wanted to mention that is three lines of output, not three lines of return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[puts](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-puts) is a method that accepts one or more arguments and writes them (their #inspect-ed value) to an IO object separated by a newline.  As written you are trying to assign puts a value rather than passing the values as parameters.

Try this

```
puts "1, 2, X",
     "4, 0, 6",
     "X, 8, 9"
```

That's passing three strings to puts and preserves your desired readability.

Answer (score 1):

```
moveOne = gets.to_i
if moveOne == 5
   puts "1,2,X"
   puts "4,O,6"
   puts "X,8,9"
end
```

P.S: Please try to learn more before posting a question.